# Point $C_1$ divides $AB$, Point$ C_2$ divides $AC_1$, $C_3$ Divides $C_2C_1$, $C_4$ Divides $C_3C_2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, limits

with segment $AB = l$, $C_n$ are all points that divide $C_{n-1}C_{n-2}$.

Question is: Determine the limiting position of $C_n$ as ${n\to \infty} $

I know it can be written as $a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}{2}$ with $a_0 = 0$ , $a_1=\frac{l}{2}$ and $n\ge 2$ and the limiting $a_n$ is the limiting $C_n$, but i can't really proceed from here.

So how to solve this problem? and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_0=0,a_1=\dfrac{1}{2},a_2=\dfrac{1}{4},a_3=\dfrac{3}{8},a_4=\dfrac{5}{16},4a_5=\dfrac{11}{32}\\a_0=\dfrac{-2+2^1}{3.2^1},a_1=\dfrac{2+2^2}{3.2^2},a_2=\dfrac{-2+2^3}{3.2^3}....
\\a_{n-1}=\dfrac{2(-1)^n+2^n}{3.2^n}\\a_n=\dfrac{1}{3}\dfrac{2(-1)^{n+1}+2^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}\\a_n=\dfrac{1}{3}(2(\dfrac{-1}{2})^{n+1}+1)\\$$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\dfrac{1}{3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}Cn$$

Comment: Thank you! so in this kind of problems, i should try to get a formula that expresses them? like what you did with $a_{n-1}$, and isn't $a_n = \frac{1}{3}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}+2^n}{2^n}$?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry I missed the edit

Comment: So how did you find the $a_{n-1}$ formula? Is it purely by deduction?

Comment: in fact it's not 100% guessing, I've faced this problem before so it was easier to guess it.

Comment: When you faced it for the first time, how were you able to solve it? sorry for adding unrelated questions.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Comment: Oh it's actually fairly simple using the link you gave me! I thought sequences like these are hard to find but it's actually really simple! thank you.